# Django: FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.11

When i'm trying to use update or create query it's gives error `FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model`

Here it is my models.py

```
class Base(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Graph(Base):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey("Sensor")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    query = models.TextField()
    javascript = models.TextField()
    args = models.TextField()
    server_details = models.ForeignKey("ServerDetails")
```

Now I want to update or create query of Graph

Here it is I'm trying to do

```
@is_login_valid
def save_graph(request):
    params = json.loads(request.body)
    ser_obj = ServerDetails.objects.get(id=params['server_details']['id'])
    sensor = Sensor.objects.get(id=1)
    rrs_obj, created = Graph.objects.update_or_create(
        id=params.get('id'),
        defaults={
            "name": params.get('name'),
            "query": params.get('query'),
            "javascript": params.get('javascript'),
            "args": params.get('args'),
            "server_details": ser_obj,
            "created_by": request.user,
            "sensor": sensor
        }
    )
    return JsonResponse({
        "validation": "Graph saved successfully",
        "status": True
    })
```

When I'm trying to update_or_create its gives following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/nikhil/general-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/home/nikhil/general-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/home/nikhil/general-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/nikhil/Projects/myProject/myProject/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in wrap
>       return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/nikhil/Projects/myProject/myProject/SensorMonitor/views.py", line 127, in save_graph
>       "sensor": sensor
>
> File "/home/nikhil/general-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/nikhil/general-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 476, in update_or_create
>       lookup, params = self._extract_model_params(defaults, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/nikhil/general-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 534, in _extract_model_params
>       "', '".join(sorted(invalid_params)),
>
> FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model Graph: 'created_by', 'query', 'sensor', 'server_details'.

Comment: Your example looks ok to me. Please show the actual code and the full traceback. What is `Base`?

Comment: @Alasdair See my updated question

Comment: Your code in your question doesn't seem to match `"created_by": request.user` from the traceback.

Comment: It's generally better to wrap your traceback in a code block than in a quote block; then the newlines are preserved and the traceback is more readable.

Comment: As per Alasdair's comments: 1/ your traceback has `MyModel`, but your code shows `Mymodel`; 2/ `Mymodel` does have `name` and `query` fields (but not `created_by`), yet the traceback claims there are three fields invalid.

Comment: Alternatively: you actually have both a model `MyModel` and a model `Mymodel`, and are confusing the two (not surprising, given the choice of names).

Comment: @Evert See my updated question

Comment: It strongly suggests that you have multiple `Graph` models, and they are mixed up. You could start with adding some debug print functions, e.g. `print([f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()])` and `print(Graph.__file__)` in the `save_graph` view (I assume you're using the development server), to see what the `Graph` model actually contains.